# Adding new table in rest api of prestashop webservice

Tags: php, web-services, rest, prestashop

I've been successful in creating an extra table in the **prestashop** products table throught **rest api of webservice** , however the api link **http://127.0.0.1/prestashop/api/wb3d/1** wb3d is the new table which I have created in webservice . Which holds a path to an images directory somewhere on the web . This link when opened shows the data which has been saved in the database as seen in the following image below

[image]
**model** is directory name on the web, so this **api(wb3d)** has been associated with the     **product table** in the webservice the **link:http://127.0.0.1/prestashop/api/products/1** when I open this link . The entry of the association is shown but the data is not shown **refer the below image **
         [image]

The highlighted area shows the wb3d table associated with the product table throught rest api of webservice . I'm unable to associate the wb3d tale data with product table data. So I can use it in other devices through webservice

This is what I have tried so far

```
    <?php
class ProductMergeCore extends ObjectModel

{  
    public $product_id;
    public $id_wb3d;
    public $directory_name;
    public static $definition = array(
    'table' => 'wb3d',
    'primary' => 'id_wb3d',
    'fields' => array(
    'id_wb3d' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT,  'required' => true),
    'product_id' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'required' => true),
    'directory_name' => array('type' => self::TYPE_STRING,  'required' =>false, 'size' => 64),
     ),
     );
    protected $webserviceParameters = array();
    }
    ?>
```

**productmerge.php** is responsible for creating an associate table entry in product table.

```
 <?php 

  Class Product extends ProductCore

  {

   public $extrafield;



public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)

 {


    $this->webserviceParameters['associations']['wb3d'] = array('resource'    => 'wb3d','fields' => array('directory_name' => array('required' => true)));

    parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);

 }

}
?>
```

In this **product.php** which is for overriding the **product class** for passing the **extra parameters**  through **webserviceparameters()** and then calling the parent **constructor** of the **product class**

```
    <?php
    class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore
    {
    public static function getResources()
    {
    $resources=parent::getResources();
    $resources['wb3d'] = array('description' => 'images path', 'class' =>   'ProductMerge');
    ksort($resources);
    return $resources;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**WebserviceRequest.php** class is a override class for the WebserviceRequest class which shows the description of the table entry in the webservice

These are the files which are required to get the things done. **What I'm trying to achieve is the associated table (wb3d) data should be available within the products table through webservice rest api call**.

Comment: why you like to add it in the product class, if you like to get the product directory information try to request wb3d webservice, which you should add its class

Comment: wb3d is a directory which holds images on the web so i.m storing a path in the directory_name field of wb3d table. what i need to achieve is the product directory should include this directory also,, so i don have to do more than one api call from any other device , those images belong to the product so .. i need this wb3d table associated with the product table

Comment: I see a product_id in wb3d, what to do for? if you see the stock quantity for a product, it's stored in a unique webservice (stock_available), even it's included in the product asociations webservice, what i sugget is to use a custom webservice for that

Comment: yes you got my case here, wb3d is a custom webservice but i need to associate it in the products webservice.. but as u can see the 2nd image of my post  the directory_name field  is empty. but data is visible if i make a direct call to the wb3d webservice..i.m not able to associate this wb3d into products webservice..same way as u said for stocks_available..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to add other webservice table as your association to your product , you can take a look at how associations is done in **category.php** located in *prestashop/classes*.

```
'associations' => array(
     'categories' => array('getter' => 'getChildrenWs', 'resource' => 'category', )         
)
```

as you can see there is a parameter named **getter** which gets the value from 
*getChildrenWs* which is a method in category.php which fetches the data from database.

so in your case: in **Product.php**

```
$this->webserviceParameters['associations']['wb3d'] = array('resource' => 'wb3d',
                                                            'getter' => 'yourMethodName',
                                                            'fields' => array('directory_name' => array('required' => true));
```

and create a method named '**yourMethodName**' in Product.php

```
public function yourMethodName()
{
  //copy the getChildrenWs method which is in Category.php  and alter it to ur needs
}
```

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for i will try this out and let you know here Thanks for your time

Comment: This helped me the solve the problem and i also understood the prestashop module work flow very much i will post code ,, which achieves my own question here . Thanks for your time @kiran