# Prestashop : Enable paypal payment verification webservice

Tags: paypal, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have developed `Prestashop` android client application with default webservices (i.e. using cloud store). Currently I have been working on PayPal payment integration for mobile client with MSDK.

Ref : https://github.com/p...Pal-Android-SDK

And transactions are working fine with my sand box business and buyer account credentials.But as PayPal mobile SDK integration, successful payment data need to verified by a server(as per my thought Prestashop) with PayPal. 
After a successful payment is made with the MSDK 2.x, the MSDK returns data to app about the payment (received by the MSDK from the REST API). Here is a sample response:

```
{
    "client": {
        "environment": "sandbox",
        "paypal_sdk_version": "2.0.0",
        "platform": "iOS",
        "product_name": "PayPal iOS SDK;"
    },
    "response": {
        "create_time": "2014-02-12T22:29:49Z",
        "id": "PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI",
        "intent": "sale",
        "state": "approved"
    },
    "response_type": "payment"
}
```

And the server need to call PayPal services to confirm that the payment is authentic, for the expected amount and currency, and that we are the recipient of the payment.

Ref : https://developer.pa...mobile-payment/

I know that Prestashop support Paypal module for web version.I need to know that is PayPal module provides webservices to achieve the verification, if it so how to enable it.

By the way I'am not expert in php :(

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The PayPal module has a class called `CallApiPaypalPlus.php` which can make the verification for you by calling its method `lookUpPayment($paymentId)`. You need to either expose that class to the WebService or (better yet, just to be safe) create a new module and ObjectModel associated with the specific use case you want (confirming payments), expose that instead of the PayPal class and use it to send over the payment ID to the server. Instructions on the webservice can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971409/adding-new-table-in-rest-api-of-prestashop-webservice

Comment: ...and here: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/360689-adding-a-new-resource-to-the-webservice-from-a-module/